# Difference between Convert.ToDecimal(string) & Decimal.Parse(string)

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference in C# between `Convert.ToDecimal(string)` and `Decimal.Parse(string)`?

In what scenarios would you use one over the other?

What impact does it have on performance?

What other factors should I be taking into consideration when choosing between the two?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From [bytes.com](http://bytes.com/forum/thread266344.html):

> The Convert class is designed to
>   convert a wide range of Types, so you
>   can convert more types to Decimal than
>   you can with Decimal.Parse, which can
>   only deal with String. On the other
>   hand Decimal.Parse allows you to
>   specify a NumberStyle.
>
> Decimal and decimal are aliases and
>   are equal.
>
> For Convert.ToDecimal(string),
>   Decimal.Parse is called internally.
>
> Morten Wennevik [C# MVP]

Since Decimal.Parse is called internally by Convert.ToDecimal, if you have ***extreme*** performance requirements you might want to stick to Decimal.Parse, it will save a stack frame.

Comment: Unless, of course, Convert.ToDecimal and/or Decimal.Parse gets inlined during compilation or even during JIT. IOW, ~~purformance~~

Answer (score 60):

There is one important difference to keep in mind:

`Convert.ToDecimal` will return `0` if it is given a `null` string.

`decimal.Parse` will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the string you want to parse is `null`.

Answer (score 18):

One factor that you might not have thought of is the `Decimal.TryParse` method.  Both `Convert.ToDecimal` and `Parse` throw exceptions if they cannot convert the string to the proper decimal format.  The TryParse method gives you a nice pattern for input validation.

```
decimal result;
if (decimal.TryParse("5.0", out result))
   ; // you have a valid decimal to do as you please, no exception.
else
   ; // uh-oh.  error message time!
```

This pattern is very incredibly awesome for error-checking user input.

Answer (score 3):

One common suggestion related to original topic - please use `TryParse()` as soon as you not really sure that input string parameter WILL be correct number format representation.

Answer (score 1):

Major Difference between `Convert.ToDecimal(string)` and `Decimal.Parse(string)`
is that Convert handles `Null` whereas the other throws an exception

Note: It won't handle empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToDecimal apparently does not always return 0.  In my linq statement

```
var query = from c in dc.DataContext.vw_WebOrders
select new CisStoreData()
{
       Discount = Convert.ToDecimal(c.Discount)
};
```

Discount is still null after converting from a Decimal? that is null.  However, outside a Linq statement, I do get a 0 for the same conversion.  Frustrating and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that Convert.ToDecimal is the way to go in most cases because it handles NULL, it, however, does not handle empty string very well. So, the following function might help:

```
'object should be a string or a number
Function ConvertStringToDecimal(ByVal ValueToConvertToDecimal As Object) As Decimal
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValueToConvertToDecimal.ToString) = False Then
        Return Convert.ToDecimal(ValueToConvertToDecimal)
    Else
        Return Convert.ToDecimal(0)
    End If
End Function
```