# Convert a string to Decimal(10,2)

Tags: asp.net

how can i convert a string to a Decimal(10,2) in C#?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73%28VS.96%29.aspx), especially if the string is coming from a user.

You'll want to use `TryParse` if there's *any* chance the string cannot be converted to a Decimal.  `TryParse` allows you to test if the conversion will work without throwing an Exception.

Comment: Link's stale.  Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse

Answer (score 1):

You got to be careful with that, because some cultures uses dots as a thousands separator and comma as a decimal separator.

My proposition for a secure string to decimal converstion:

```
    public static decimal parseDecimal(string value)
    {
        value = value.Replace(" ", "");
        if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == ",")
        {
            value = value.Replace(".", ",");
        }
        else
        {
            value = value.Replace(",", ".");
        }
        string[] splited = value.Split(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]);
        if (splited.Length > 2)
        {
            string r = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < splited.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == splited.Length - 1)
                    r += System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
                r += splited[i];
            }
            value = r;
        }
        return decimal.Parse(value);
    }
```

The loop is in case that string contains both, decimal and thousand separator

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string test = "123";

decimal test2 = Convert.ToDecimal(test);

//decimal test2 = Decimal.Parse(test);

//decimal test2;
   // if (decimal.TryParse(test, out result))
//{ //valid }
   //else

   //{ //Exception }

labelConverted.Text = test2.toString();
```

[Decimal Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/decimal)

[Difference between Convert.ToDecimal(string) & Decimal.Parse(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89203/difference-between-convert-todecimalstring-decimal-parsestring)

Regards