# Using Convert.ToDecimal() causes rounding of value in C#. How to overcome this issue?

Tags: c#, optimization

Some_Variable has a value 295523.93 returned from database. [DataType: money (Transact-SQL data type. Database used is SQL2005) ]

- (decimal)Some_Variable gives value = 295523.93  [DataType: decimal]

  (float)Some_Variable gives value = 295523.938   [DataType: float]

  (decimal)((float)Some_Variable) gives value = 295523.9 [DataType: decimal]

  Convert.ToDecimal((float)Some_Variable) gives value = 295523.9 [DataType: decimal]
  (

  (decimal)((double)Some_Variable) gives value = 295523.93 [DataType: decimal]

  Convert.ToDecimal((double)Some_Variable) gives value = 295523.93 [DataType: decimal]

Why does the below give 295523.9 in rare circumstances(one occurrence since the project is live for over 2 years)

- Convert.ToDecimal((float)Some_Variable) gives value = 295523.9 [DataType: decimal]

Im considering to use **(decimal)Some_Variable which gives value = 295523.93**, but curious if there is any explanation other than its related to how numbers are stored in memory(binary)?

[Edit]: While the actual value comes from the database, for issue reproduction I have assigned it the value directly in the below example. Please find below the code screenshot along with Watch window.[image: Code snippet to reproduce issue along with Watch window]

Comment: This may be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89203/difference-between-convert-todecimalstring-decimal-parsestring

Comment: What is the type of `Some_Variable`? (Both the compile-time type and the execution-time type of the value would be useful.)

Comment: If decimal causes issues, have you tried using double instead?

Comment: Show the declaration of Some_Variable

Comment: Showing some actual code and details on this mystery type "Money" would help make this question answerable.

Comment: Replace your text description by a code sample that initializes a value, does the conversion, and asserts the result you expect.  If the assertion fails, others will easily be able to run your code and explain to you exactly why.

Comment: @Heinzi:I have included the code snippet and "watch" window to show the issue. Im doing maintenance of the code , and currently its programmed as "Convert.ToDecimal((float)Some_Variable);"

Comment: This is all entirely normal. A value of type float is only capable of storing 7 significant digits. So only the digits 2955239 can be accurate, the rest of them are just random noise digits.  The implicit conversion operator that converts float to decimal knows this and simply hacks off the noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` has extremely small precision (corresponding to approximately 7-8 decimal digits). For example, these are subsequent float numbers in your range:

```
01001000100100000100110001111101 --> 295523.90625
01001000100100000100110001111110 --> 295523.9375
01001000100100000100110001111111 --> 295523.96875
```

Thus, a value of, for example, `295523.92` would be rounded to either the first or the second of those values. Since the eighth significant digit is so inaccurate, it does not make sense to keep it when converting to decimal. This behaviour is described in the [documentation of `Convert.ToDecimal(float)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/he38a8ca.aspx) (emphasis by me):

> The Decimal value returned by this method contains a maximum of seven significant digits. **If the value parameter contains more than seven significant digits, it is rounded using rounding to nearest.**

`295523.93` has eight significant digits. Rounded to seven significant digits using "round to nearest" yields `295523.9`.

Comment: This is correct. Casting or converting from `float` (`Single`) or `double` to `decimal` is thus ***not*** an injective mapping, even in the domain where a `decimal` has superior precision. Two distinct but "close" `float` values can be projected to the same `decimal`. A workaround exists.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Correct, the workaround being, for example, `float.ToString("r")`, which outputs a *"string that can round-trip to an identical number"*.