# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format in C#

Tags: c#, string

Can anyone help me resolve the following error in c#.

`System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`

Below is the code:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
txtTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c", culture);

private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...................................

    decimal totalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice.Text.Split(',')[0]) * 1000;
    decimal finalPrice = totalPrice - (totalPrice / 100) * discount;

    // ......................................
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niCIK.png)

Comment: What is the content of txtTotalPrice.Text at the moment in which you click the button?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/89235/34092

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Check the line `decimal totalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPrice.Text.Split(',')[0]) * 1000;` - the textbox is the source of your problem. You should validate the value of the textbox to ensure that it's what you think it is, rather than naively feeding the value into the convert function.

Comment: txtTotalPrice.Text using when we click btnCheck_Click. I don't why when I change code like below it no error:                                           
 CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("vi-VN");
txtTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c", culture);

private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...................................

 double totalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotalPrice.Text.Split(',')[0]) * 1000;
  double finalPrice = totalPrice - (totalPrice / 100) * discount;

    // ......................................
}

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is, your value to convert to decimal is not convertible.

Please see the modified code and make it resolved if works for you.

```
   decimal finalPrice;   
   decimal totalPrice;
    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TO check if txtTotalPrice is not null
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotalPrice.Text))
        {
            string decimalValue = txtTotalPrice.Text.Split(',')[0];
            decimal val;
            // Try to convert it to decimal.
            if (decimal.TryParse(decimalValue, out val))
            {
                // your logic here if able to convert it.
                finalPrice = val- (val/ 100) * discount;

            }
        }
   }
```

Please let me know if you have any other doubt.

Comment: wow! it work for me. but for for finalPrice get value 0 why ? help me. thnaks

code like is below :

Comment: CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");  when I change is code to CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("vi-VN"); your code is work . Why ?

Comment: I just want to use "en-US" only .Help me resolve. thank.

Comment: can you please see the value in txtTotalPrice.Text?

Comment: txtTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c"); when I am debug I saw it have value.

Answer (score 0):

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

ERROR

private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string UpdateQuery = "UPDATE useraccount SET Student_ID_No='"+textBox1.Text+"',FirstName='"+textBox2.Text+"',MiddleName='"+textBox3.Text+"',LastName='"+textBox4.Text+"',MobileNo='"+textBox5.Text+"',Position='"+comboBox1.Text+"',Password='"+textBox6.Text+"',Question='"+comboBox2.Text+"',Answer="+textBox7.Text+" WHERE id="+int.Parse(textBoxID.Text);
        executeMyQuery(UpdateQuery);
        populateDGV();

    }
```